# Dynamics CRM Business Process Error An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Hello im trying to write a plugin for ms dynamics crm 2011. The plugin fetches related records from contract line and then is supposed to create records for the invoice line entity. The code runs perfect if there is only one record returned by fetchxml however if it loops around for a contract that has more than one contract line the following error is thrown:

Business Process Error 
An item with the same key has already been added

Im thinking i need a unique id for each record or something please have a look at my code below.

```
Entity invoiceline = new Entity("invoicedetail");
foreach (Entity contractdetail in contractdetails.Entities)
{
    tracingService.Trace("loop no. " + loopint + "  " + "InvoiceID: " + stringinvoiceid);
    loopint++;
    invoiceline["invoiceid"] = new EntityReference("invoice", invoiceid);

    //collect data from fetchxml
    var title = contractdetail.Attributes["title"];
    decimal quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(contractdetail.Attributes["initialquantity"]);
    var price = contractdetail.Attributes["price"];
    bool booleanover = true;

    //add to invoiceline array
    invoiceline.Attributes.Add("productdescription", title);
    invoiceline.Attributes.Add("quantity", quantity);
    invoiceline.Attributes.Add("priceperunit", price);
    invoiceline.Attributes.Add("isproductoverridden", booleanover);
    //invoiceline.Attributes.Add("invoicedetailid", invoiceid);

    //add too database
    service.Create(invoiceline);
    tracingService.Trace("Created:" + title + " record");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are using `Attributes.Add`.

The attribute collection is actually a dictionary, you can't add the same key (`productdescription`, `quantity`, etc) to a dictionary twice.

So that entity record you have loaded already has those keys (because you included it in the `columnset`)

The easiest way to avoid this is just to use: `invoiceline["quanity"] = quantity;`

This will overwrite the existing value for that key - or if it doesn't exist add a new key value pair to the dictionary.

Related reading: [Dictionary.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put like this:

```
Entity invoiceLine;
foreach (Entity contractDetail in contractDetails.Entities)
{
    invoiceline = new Entity("invoicedetail");
    ...
}
```